# Why is TensorBoard localhost:6006 only displaying a white page?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, tensorboard

I'm using a windows 10 desktop with tensorflow GPU installed.

When trying to run this code that I copied from the TensorBoard website the localhost page that displays after running the below code is just a white page. I've tried using "tensorboard --logdir logs/fit" and an explicit IP address from the terminal however nothing is working. Also I'm receiving this message back from the terminal after the model is retrained

"Serving TensorBoard on localhost; to expose to the network, use a proxy or pass --bind_all
TensorBoard 2.1.1 at http://localhost:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
E0429 20:12:03.996999   876 directory_watcher.py:255] File ./logs\1588205514.6450007\train\events.out.tfevents.1588205515.DE
SKTOP.14952.259.v2 updated even though the current file is ./logs\1588205514.6450007\train\events.out.tfevents.1588205515.DE
SKTOP.profile-empty"

Not sure where to go from here, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import time

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0


def create_model():
    return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])


tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs\\{}'.format(time.time()))

model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          epochs=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[tensorboard])

model.save('TestBoard.model')
```

Comment: I think you could try two modifications. (1) You don't have a `fit` folder in your `log_dir` creation, you just have `logs` follow by `time.time()`, either change the tensorboard cmd line our the tensorboard callback. (2) On tensorboard callback, try using `profile_batch=0` to completely disable profiling.

Comment: @n1colas.m Okay thanks I'll give it a shot!